# How can I find POEdit errors

Tags: poedit

I'm getting duplicate message definition errors in POEdit and I cannot update from that catalog.

POEdit doesn't show details and the line numbers in the errors don't match.

How can I find what is wrong?

```
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: /var/folders/qt/cg8qlhc159v9s15kmhy1h4440000gn/T/poeditgGtdFw/1input.po:2791: duplicate message definition...
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: /var/folders/qt/cg8qlhc159v9s15kmhy1h4440000gn/T/poeditgGtdFw/1input.po:65: ...this is the location of the first definition
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: /var/folders/qt/cg8qlhc159v9s15kmhy1h4440000gn/T/poeditgGtdFw/1input.po:2827: duplicate message definition...
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: /var/folders/qt/cg8qlhc159v9s15kmhy1h4440000gn/T/poeditgGtdFw/1input.po:1530: ...this is the location of the first definition
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: /Users/burakkilic/Applications/Poedit.app/Contents/PlugIns/GettextTools.bundle/Contents/MacOS/bin/msgmerge: found 2 fatal errors
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: Entries in the catalogue are probably incorrect.
Sat Mar 11 16:51:31 2017: Updating the catalogue failed. Click on 'Details >>' for details.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I find what is wrong?

```
msgfmt -v -c /path/to/1input.po
```

Comment: msgfmt -v -c tr.po showed where the problems are. Thank you very much, accepted as the answer.

Comment: How can you run this on Windows?

Comment: @icc97, msgfmt.exe is located in Poedit\GettextTools\bin

Comment: perfect!! Just adding a tip, you need to specify the file when call this command e.j.  msgfmt -v -c path/to/your/file

Comment: If you are running on windows 10, just use linux subsystem to run this command (gettext installed is needed) - worked for me.

Comment: Poedit uses gettext commands internally and bundles the appropriate binaries because it needs them, so there's no need to find them elsewhere.